# In NDB, is the id of a key is binarysafe?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In NDB, is the id of a key is  binarysafe ?

I want to use some binary string as id  ^_^ (example the txid.decode('hex') of the bitcoin trade)

Answer (score 1):

Keys can use either a numeric id or a string name.

In your case you can convert the binary string to hex and store it as a string as the name.

Comment: I wouldn't count on null-bytes in the string id always round-tripping.

Comment: Under what conditions might a binary sequence not translate to a hex string?  Don't null bytes just translate to 0?  It's bulky and not space efficient, but I'm not sure where you'll hit conversion issues.  Unless maybe if you have a non-byte aligned number of bits at one end.

Answer (score 0):

It might or might not be (Its not designed to be) It might be better to leverage the uuid library

```
import uuid

client_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-",'')
```